# Webpack vs Parcel

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, parcel, parceljs

What is advantage and disadvantage between webpack and parcel

[image]

Webpack:

https://webpack.js.org

Parcel:

https://parceljs.org

Comment: Read this:https://x-team.com/blog/rollup-webpack-parcel-comparison/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to worry about configuring everything and your needs are common needs, you should go directly with parcel. Parcel provides defaults (for babel-preset-env, post-css, html, etc) that fits most scenarios and works for everybody. You don't have to worry about configuring anything.

From the other hand, if you need a more customization, you should go with webpack. Keep in mind that you will have to setup everything that you need, explicitly set those things.

Comment: Technically want will be major impact area if i start using parcel, eg : build output path or hashing...etc

Comment: You won't have any impact.